# version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by ...)

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, boost, gcc4.9

When I run my program following a compile, I get the following error:

> ./prog: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by ./prog)
>   ./prog: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version`GLIBCXX_3.4.19' not found (required by ./prog)
>   ./prog: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /home/arman/lib/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib/libboost_serialization.so.1.55.0)

I have both boost 1.55.0 and gcc 4.9.0 installed in `~/lib/boost_1_55_0` and `~/lib/gcc-4.9.0` respectively, and I'm guessing this is why I'm having problems, but I'm unsure about how to go about fixing it.

my `~/.profile` contains the following line:

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/lib/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: FAQ: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.how_to_set_paths

Answer (score 46, accepted):

GCC 4.9 introduces a newer C++ ABI version than your system libstdc++ has, so you need to tell the loader to use this newer version of the library by adding that path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Unfortunately, I cannot tell you straight off where the libstdc++ so for your GCC 4.9 installation is located, as this depends on how you configured GCC. So you need something in the style of:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/lib/gcc-4.9.0/lib:/home/user/lib/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Note the actual path may be different (there might be some subdirectory hidden under there, like `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.0´ or similar).

Comment: In this case it's likely to be in `/home/user/lib/gcc-4.9.0/lib64`

Comment: For help with qtox (not sure why this page is the first hit for fixing qtox) please see https://github.com/tux3/qTox/issues/3358#issuecomment-233700842

Comment: For those running in an anaconda environment, it will be `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/anaconda3/lib`