# Installing node.js on raspberry pi 2

Tags: node.js, debian, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, dpkg

I have installed Raspbian on my Raspberry Pi 2 and now I am trying to install node.js on it, however I am hitting an issue.

I followed the instructions and typed these commands into the terminal

```
wget http://node-arm.herokuapp.com/node_latest_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i node_latest_armhf.deb
```

But when I check the version of node using

```
node -v
```

I get this error:

```
node: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by node)
node: /lib/arm-linus-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16' not found (required by node)
```

I am quite new to using raspberry pi, so any help to fix this issue would be great!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be moved to the http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh, I did not realise there was a subdomain for raspberry pi questions. Do I need to move it or will it be done by admins?

Comment: possible duplicate of [version \`CXXABI\_1.3.8' not found (required by ...)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494103/version-cxxabi-1-3-8-not-found-required-by)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Just putting the response from @Prashant Pathak above here:

1. Download latest nodejs build for Raspberry Pi:

   ```
   wget https://nodejs.org/download/release/v0.10.0/node-v0.10.0-linux-arm-pi.tar.gz
   ```
2. Unpack files in local directory:

   ```
   cd /usr/local

   sudo tar xzvf ~/node-v0.10.0-linux-arm-pi.tar.gz --strip=1
   ```

That's it. 
You can confirm it's there by checking the node version with:

```
node -v
```

and:

```
npm -v
```

The actual url to get the files for node will change as the version changes, you can always see the list of files available for download here: 
http://nodejs.org/download/

All these instructions came from: 
http://www.robert-drummond.com/2015/01/08/server-side-javascript-on-a-raspberry-pi-how-to-install-node-js-2/

Comment: Since the file now is .tar.xz the command should be *sudo tar xJf*

Comment: Work very well installing this version : https://nodejs.org/download/release/v0.10.9/node-v0.10.9-linux-arm-pi.tar.gz

Comment: @SoldierCop you can change the .tar.xz to .tar.gz they still available. I can confirm that in nodejs v8.11.2

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively you can upgrade your GCC to V4.8 for this package to work!

## Option 1 (the better option):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8 g++-4.8
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.6 20
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 50
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.6 20
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8 50
```

## Options 2: Upgrade to Debian Jessie

Replace all instances of "wheezy" in  `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

After this you download the Node.js using command line as follows:

```
wget http://node-arm.herokuapp.com/node_latest_armhf.deb
```

Next step is to install the Node.js:

```
sudo dpkg -i node_latest_armhf.deb
```

Finally, you can verify the installation:

```
node -v
```

These instructions are mentioned on http://node-arm.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Thanks Prashant, I tried option1, however I still received the same error

Comment: @slim1801 "GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found" issue is basically due to latest upgrade. You can try archive verison of node.js by following command:-  wget http://node-arm.herokuapp.com/node_archive_armhf.deb  sudo dpkg -i node_archive_armhf.deb

Answer (score 6):

That runs for me:
http://blog.wia.io/installing-node-js-v4-0-0-on-a-raspberry-pi/

Raspberry Pi Model A, B, B+ and Compute Module

```
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.0.0/node-v4.0.0-linux-armv6l.tar.gz
tar -xvf node-v4.0.0-linux-armv6l.tar.gz
cd node-v4.0.0-linux-armv6l
```

Raspberry Pi 2 Model B

```
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.0.0/node-v4.0.0-linux-armv7l.tar.gz
tar -xvf node-v4.0.0-linux-armv7l.tar.gz
cd node-v4.0.0-linux-armv7l
sudo cp -R * /usr/local/
```

Answer (score 2):

use nodejs instead of node

> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nodejs

for npm

> sudo apt-get install npm

Answer (score 0):

The Latest Node is released for the below platforms, which helped for my old R-PI which is of model name    : ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l)

https://nodejs.org/download/release/v4.1.0/

node-v4.1.0-linux-arm64.tar.gz                     17-Sep-2015 04:24            10886090

node-v4.1.0-linux-arm64.tar.xz                     17-Sep-2015 04:24             7100824

node-v4.1.0-linux-armv6l.tar.gz                    17-Sep-2015 17:37            10763504

node-v4.1.0-linux-armv6l.tar.xz                    18-Sep-2015 00:15             7005048

node-v4.1.0-linux-armv7.tar.gz                     17-Sep-2015 05:17            10773951

node-v4.1.0-linux-armv7.tar.xz                     17-Sep-2015 05:18             7004760

node-v4.1.0-linux-armv7l.tar.gz                    18-Sep-2015 12:58            10773951

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following command:
wget node-arm.herokuapp.com/node_archive_armhf.deb

then 
sudo dpkg -i node_archive_armhf.deb

node -v should work now!