# RHEL7 - /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found

Tags: linux, gcc, rhel

I know this question has been asked for many times while I still get stuck with it.
I have reviewed all answers previously asked like 
[version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by ...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494103/version-cxxabi-1-3-8-not-found-required-by)

[How to fix: [program name] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by [program name])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357033/how-to-fix-program-name-usr-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-libstdc-so-6-version-cxx)

and I've read https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.how_to_set_paths

My system is RHEL7, I had a gcc 4.8 installed before, and I install gcc 4.9 with `yum -y install devtoolset-3-gcc devtoolset-3-gcc-c++`

Then gcc 4.9 is successfully installed.
With `gcc -v`, I get

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr --mandir=/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/share/man --infodir=/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-plugin --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.9.2-20150212/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install --with-cloog=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.9.2-20150212/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/cloog-install --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 20150212 (Red Hat 4.9.2-6) (GCC)
```

Then I set my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` following the others' suggestions like:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.2:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
```

However, the error still exits and it seems my newer version gcc4.9 doesn't work. 
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 9):

The problem is occurring because the `devtoolset-x` packages actually just wrap the standard system `libstdc++.so` so even tho' you have a new compiler, you still have the old ABI (application binary interface). So what you really need is a whole new compiler! Which will include a new library of its own.

To build the compiler you'll need to install some dependencies:

```
sudo yum install gmp-devel mpfr-devel libmpc-devel
```

You can download a newer version of GCC [from one of the official mirrors](https://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html), grab a version such as `gcc-8.3.0.tar.gz`, unpack it and in that directory

```
./configure --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++ --prefix=$HOME/local
make -j5
make -j install
```

Then whenever you need a modern ABI,

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/local/lib64
```

and everything may start working.  If your application spawns its own environment (such as Steam), you may want to place the libraries within a path it is searching already.

The "duplicate" answers are either wrong or outdated; this is the correct solution as of today. I know because I tried them all, and this is what actually works...

Comment: I'm guessing somebody wanted to avoid manual compilation and find a distro package, but this appears to be the right solution for rhel7 unfortunately !

Comment: did the yum install thing but still said it couldn't find the dependencies. Running `./contrib/download_prerequisites` from the path I extracted to worked.