# cannot import matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have installed the matplotlib in python,and when I `import matplotlib`,it works well.But when I `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`,the command line prompt me that an importerror occurred.

```
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /home/nju/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_path.so)
```

How can I solve the problem?
Thanks very much

Comment: Does `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` exist on your system?

Comment: Yes.There is a `libstdc++.so.6` in the path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494103/version-cxxabi-1-3-8-not-found-required-by) ?

Comment: I guess this is a strong indication that you have in incomplete or broken matplotlib install or that versions are not matching.

Comment: I update the libstdc++.so.6,and it works.Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-glx
```

Above command is from the link below.

https://github.com/ContinuumIO/docker-images/issues/49